# Looking for the fastest way to find the exact overlap between two arrays of equal length in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for the optimal (fastest) way to find the exact overlap between two arrays in numpy. Given two arrays x and y

```
x = array([1,0,3,0,5,0,7,4],dtype=int)
y = array([1,4,0,0,5,0,6,4],dtype=int)
```

What I want to get is, an array of the same length that contains only the numbers from both vectors that are equal:

```
array([1,0,0,0,5,0,0,4])
```

First I tried

```
x&y
array([1,0,0,0,5,0,6,4])
```

Then I realised that this is always true for two numbers if they are > 0.

Comment: Sounds like a sequence alignment package is what you need, are you doing bioinformatics?

Comment: Your last sentence should be "always true for two numbers if they are !=0"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
result = numpy.where(x == y, x, 0)
```

Have a look at [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) documentation for explanation.  Basically, `numpy.where(a, b, c)`, for a condition `a` returns an array of shape `a`, and with values from `b` or `c`, depending upon whether the corresponding element of `a` is true or not.  `b` or `c` can be scalars.

By the way, `x & y` is not necessarily "always true" for two positive numbers.  It does [bitwise-and](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) for elements in `x` and `y`:

```
x = numpy.array([2**p for p in xrange(10)])
# x is [  1   2   4   8  16  32  64 128 256 512]
y = x - 1
# y is [  0   1   3   7  15  31  63 127 255 511]
x & y
# result: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

This is because the bitwise representation of each element in `x` is of the form `1` followed by `n` zeros, and the corresponding element in `y` is `n` 1s.  In general, for two non-zero numbers `a` and `b`, `a & b` may equal zero, or non-zero but not necessarily equal to either `a` or `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy.where` is the most general solution. but in this particular case, and because it is a useful programming practice, you could use `x==y` as a mask:

```
mask = x==y  
# mask is  array([ True, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

xf = mask * x
# xf is array([1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 4])
```

or directly

```
xf = (x==y) * x
```

imagine now some data `X` (e.g. 1D for sound, 2D for an image, 3D for a movie, etc...)

```
(X<1) * -1. + (X>1) * 1.
```

returns data with values `-1` for an amplitude inferior to 1 and `1.` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

try numpy.in1d... from the documentation....

Test whether each element of a 1D array is also present in a second array.

Returns a boolean array the same length as `ar1` that is True
where an element of `ar1` is in `ar2` and False otherwise.

### Parameters

ar1 : array_like, shape (M,)
    Input array.
ar2 : array_like
    The values against which to test each value of `ar1`.
assume_unique : bool, optional
    If True, the input arrays are both assumed to be unique, which
    can speed up the calculation.  Default is False.

### Returns

mask : ndarray of bools, shape(M,)
    The values `ar1[mask]` are in `ar2`.

### See Also

numpy.lib.arraysetops : Module with a number of other functions for
                        performing set operations on arrays.

### Notes

`in1d` can be considered as an element-wise function version of the
python keyword `in`, for 1D sequences. `in1d(a, b)` is roughly
equivalent to `np.array([item in b for item in a])`.

.. versionadded:: 1.4.0

### Examples

```
test = np.array([0, 1, 2, 5, 0])
states = [0, 2]
mask = np.in1d(test, states)
mask
    array([ True, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
test[mask]
    array([0, 2, 0])
```